# VB.NET - FTP connection on other devices

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ftp, vb.net-2010, ftpwebrequest

I'm coding an application which will automatically connect to my ftp server and Download & Upload some files often.

The problem is that, the program works fine on my Laptop without a single problem. But for some strange reason the application cannot connect to my server while they are being used on other Laptops or Computers. I had even added my app to the firewall exception in windows 10. But still getting this error.

I've also tried in Windows 7 on VirtualBox which surprisingly worked fine after installing .NET 4.5. But whenever I've tried to use my app on other devices (which were Windows 10) they gave me the same error that my application was unable to connect to my server.

**My Code:**

```
Dim keycheck As String
Dim userdir as string = "demoname"
    ' For 3 months
    Dim rannum As Random
    rannum = New Random

    Try
        If My.Settings.submonth = Nothing Then
            My.Settings.submonth = String.Empty
            My.Settings.submonth = rannum.Next(100000, 1000000)
            keycheck = My.Settings.submonth
            My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("filename", "ftp://ftp.ley.xyz/" + userdir + "/ds651v1sd6v5dsv1ds65v1ds9v5dsv5sd1vds65vdsv165sd1v/" + "::Month Registration Key::_" + keycheck, "username", "password")
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Somethings wrong with your network or our server. Try again later!")
        End
    End Try
```

This works properly in my device but on other devices it only gives the error message. Although I've only tried in Windows 10 on other Devices. I've also used admin rights and Exception in Windows Defender Virus scan. But still unable to connect to my server.

Comment: **Rule #1 of debugging:** _ALWAYS_ log the exception message, type and in some cases the stack trace. The exception provides critical details of what actually went wrong with your code. Without this information you (or anybody else, in this case _**we**_) don't know what the actual problem is and therefore cannot do anything to fix it. There is an infinite amount of things that could go wrong, one can't guess.

Comment: What *"this error"*??? Show us exact exception message.

Comment: **NEVER, EVER** use `End`.  If you want to exit the application then call `Application.Exit`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Well, I've edited my code to show msgbox(ex.message) now. Will leave the error reason after trying it again later. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Will do sire.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Will do so from now on. :) But can you please tell me the reason behind it? Thank you.

Comment: `End` will basically throw an application out of memory without any regard for state, where `Application.Exit` will go through the proper process for exiting.  It's much like the difference between just turning off the power on your computer or shutting it down properly via the OS.

Comment: @jmcilhinney to turn off your pc ALWAYS cut the power supply cable c:

Comment: @jmcilhinney AND, don't forget to wash the power supply with some water and soap, dirty psu works worse than clean one c:

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for the lesson on Application.exit. Appreciate the help. :)

Comment: @SamiurRahmanSami So will you give us by editing your question, the exception message that comes out from your code?

Comment: @Simo Well, I need to test my application on someone's device who is currently unavailable due to his college. For that I'm now unable to give you guys the error message. But the moment I test it out again I'll edit my post & give my error message to seek further help. Thank you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney End is correct way to terminate your application. It is just shortcut to Environment.Exit method.

Comment: @Ondřej, here's what the documentation for the `End` statement has to say: **"The End statement stops code execution abruptly, and does not invoke the Dispose or Finalize method, or any other Visual Basic code. Object references held by other programs are invalidated. If an End statement is encountered within a Try or Catch block, control does not pass to the corresponding Finally block."**

Comment: It goes on to say: **"Because End terminates your application without attending to any resources that might be open, you should try to close down cleanly before using it. For example, if your application has any forms open, you should close them before control reaches the End statement."**

Comment: And also: **"You should use End sparingly, and only when you need to stop immediately. The normal ways to terminate a procedure (Return Statement and Exit Statement) not only close down the procedure cleanly but also give the calling code the opportunity to close down cleanly. A console application, for example, can simply Return from the Main procedure."**

Comment: So, in summary, only use `End` when you need to stop immediately, which is pretty much never.

Comment: @jmcilhinney As I wrote above, using End is same as calling Environment.Exit, which is correct way of terminating application quickly. There are lot of scenarios where you need to exit as fast as possible (usually in application initialization where nothing graphical or resource intensive is loaded). I agree that if you want to exit application from UI, you should use Application.Exit.

Comment: **"There are lot of scenarios where you need to exit as fast as possible"**. I would argue that you are misusing the word "need" in that context.